# SQL Insert from other table into new table

Tags: sql, select, insert, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE #Temporary
(
HoursThisYear int,
HoursLastYear int,
HoursBefore2010 int
)

INSERT 
INTO #Temporary (HoursThisYear)
SELECT SUM(Hours) WHEN Year = '2011' FROM WorkFlow
```

I am very new at this, and not sure what I am doing.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: And which database are you using? Different vendors do things a little differently - this might be one of those cases

Comment: Ahah! I did forget to ask a question. Something was going wrong, and for the life of me I couldn't figure it out. When != Where ://  Thank you all for your quick responses.

Comment: @brachaalizah: In the future, it's best if you provide error messages (or at least a description of the expected vs. observed behavior) rather than "something was going wrong." While this was a fairly simple fix (using `when` instead of `where` and having it before the `from`), others will be less obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for help on the INSERT syntax.

```
INSERT INTO #Temporary 
    (HoursThisYear)
    SELECT SUM(Hours) 
        FROM WorkFlow
        WHERE Year = '2011'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Temporary ( HoursThisYear int, HoursLastYear int, HoursBefore2010 int )

INSERT INTO #Temporary (HoursThisYear) 
    SELECT SUM(Hours) 
    FROM WorkFlow
    WHERE Year = '2011'
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
CREATE TABLE #Temporary
(
HoursThisYear int,
HoursLastYear int,
HoursBefore2010 int
)

INSERT 
INTO #Temporary (HoursThisYear)
SELECT SUM(Hours) 
FROM WorkFlow
WHERE Year = '2011'
```